# Rails nested form many-to-many special case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

Let consider the classic realization of many-to-many model in Rails.

```
class Order
  has_many   :order_products
  has_many   :products, through: order_products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_products
end

class Product
  has_many :order_products
  has_many :orders, through: order_products
end

class OrderProduct
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end

<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :order_products do |op|%>
  <%= op.label :amount %><br>
  <%= op.text_field :amount %>

  <% op.fields_for :product do |p|%>
     <%= p.label :name %><br>
     <%= p.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is in my case I have a full constant tables **products**, with predefined set of products. I need to show all list of **products** on create/edit view of **order** and user should set amount of each product he needs, there is no way to add additional products. **order_products** is a join table.

In classic example, user by himself can add/delete products to **products** table, in my case he can only choose the needed product from predefined set and his choose should be recorded  in **order_products** table.

The above code is given for classic case, I don't know how to fit it to my case.

I would appreciate your help.

**Addendum:**
The following is the code that I have right now

```
<%= form_<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :order_products do |op|%>
  <%= op.label :amount %><br>
  <%= op.text_field :amount %>
  <%= op.label :product_id, "Product" %>
  <%= op.select :product_id, Product.all.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] } %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I had to add the following code to order controller, in order to create all non icluded products to order with 0 amount, such that all of them are on the form. It's not the best way, do you know how to do it correctly?

```
Product.all.each { |p| order.orderproducts.push(OrderProduct.new(:product_id => p.id,:order_id => 1, :amount => 0)) if !@order.orderproducts.any?{|b| b.product_id == p.id}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need an `amount` column/attribute on `OrderProduct` and that you can remove the nested products declaration on that class.

You can then create `OrderProduct` instances from your order specifying the product that you want and the amount of that product. You don't need any nestedness for product because you have those created already.

Your form then becomes something like:

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :order_products do |op|%>
  <%= op.label :amount %><br>
  <%= op.text_field :amount %>
  <%= op.label :product_id, "Product" %>
  <%= op.select :product_id, Product.all.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] } %>
<% end %>
```

It would also be worth adding a validation to your `OrderProduct` to ensure that `amount` is a valid, positive, integer.

```
validates_numericality_of :amount, 
    :only_integer => true, 
    :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I've added the current code to the addendum in the question. The problem is I cannot get it working, it fails with 'unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end'. What do I do wrong?

Comment: You've got two `<% end %>` statements to close your form.

Comment: right, thank you, I've changed it in addendum too, but now I have something different *undefined local variable or method `form_' for*.

Comment: That was a mistake copied from your code. Fixed in my answer.

Comment: Great, thank you! One more point, the problem is I need the list of all available Products available on the form, if product is not included in order, just show it with amount 0. I don't know how to implement it correctly in Rails way, the only workaround I've added to addendum, do you know better way?

Comment: That sounds like it would work as another question. You'd need to generate the form a bit differently by iterating over all `Product`s, cross-checking whether there is an `OrderProduct` for each and setting the `amount` and a hidden `product_id` accordingly.